# upload presentations .pptx in google drive sdk

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

When I upload presentations .pptx using the SDK,  logs show that all bytes are sent, but to open them in google drive ths slides appears with errors, however if I upload the same presentation in .ppt, has not problem and appears well on google drive, using the resumable upload, this is the code.

```
byte[] myFile = readImageData(blobKey,size);
ByteArrayContent mediaContent = new ByteArrayContent(mimeType, myFile);

Drive.Files.Insert insert = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(1024 * 1024);
File file = insert.execute();
```

**UPDATE**

But if i use

```
insert.setConvert(true);
```

the presentations .pptx has not problem and appears well on google drive.